# Can't retrieve flurry ads using admob mediation

Tags: android, admob, flurry

I'm trying to use Flurry as a second Ads provider using Admob mediation. I have setup everything as the documentation is telling. But still I can't see any Ad request in my Flurry account. I do see them in my Admob account, where it does make requests to Flurry.

My logcat is showing the following:

```
11-26 20:56:11.163: E/BrowserManagement(23108): class not found: QcRilHookjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.qualcomm.qcrilhook.QcRilHook
11-26 20:56:11.193: I/Ads(23108): Trying mediation network: 3xxxxxxxxxx56545613
11-26 20:56:11.243: I/Ads(23108): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.flurry.FlurryAdapter
11-26 20:56:11.253: W/Ads(23108): Could not request interstitial ad from adapter.
11-26 20:56:11.253: W/Ads(23108): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-26 20:56:11.253: W/Ads(23108):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ca.a(Unknown Source)
```

The ClassCastException is in my view the error. However I'm not sure where to look.

Just let me know which kind of code you want to see, I can update this post.

I'm using the whole Admob cycle in requesting/ loading and showing interstitials. In the documentation it says that's all there is. I did include the flurry adapter and the flurry analytics as they are mandatory. My manifest is updated with the Flurry Activity

Comment: Show how you configure you AdView XML and code. I suspect you are passing in the Application as context instead of the Activity.

Comment: Hi William, I forgot to update this post. It is solved by Flurry support. If you want some credits you can put your comment as an answer because you are absolutely right. I passed the Ad with GetApplicationContext(), instead of "this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are passing in the Application as context instead of the Activity.